# While click OK button in There are unsaved changes error message, APEX interactive grid is getting blank. How to avoid that?

Tags: javascript, css, oracle, oracle-apex

While clicking the OK button in 'There are unsaved changes,Do you want to continue?', my interactive grid is getting blank. How to avoid the grid blank? Or How to hide the 'There are unsaved changes,Do you want to continue?' dialog page itself?
Please anybody provide the solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for a *blank* interactive grid, but can suggest something for another question: navigate to page properties and switch the **Warn on unsaved changes** property **OFF**.

Comment: Eventhough Warn on unsaved changes property OFF, 'There are unsaved changes,Do you want to continue?' message is coming.  Some validations check is there while save. With the Validation message,  'There are unsaved changes,Do you want to continue?' dialog message also coming

Comment: It is not for me. If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com, provide developer's credentials so that we could look and - possibly - help.